# The relationship between 羞 and 醜

Tags: character-components

Since 醜 is the traditional version of 丑, why is the lower part of a traditional 羞 丑 but not 醜?

I found this [羞](https://tw.18dao.net/%E6%BC%A2%E8%AA%9E%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E7%BE%9E),

> (會意兼形聲。據甲骨文,以手持羊,表示進獻。小篆從羊,從醜,醜亦聲。“醜”是手的訛變。本義:進獻)

But it doesn't explain why it is 丑.

Comment: Adding to what the others have answered, during simplification, hundreds of characters were merged with others, often characters with ancient or obscure meanings the traditional 丑. Both 醜 and 丑 are proper traditional characters with separate meanings, although over time they often started being used as popular variants, which is where many simplified characters come from. Some of them [are listed at the bottom of this page](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/简化字#合併簡化示例).

Comment: Need to be careful when citing old literature. You need to make sure what you cite is not a transformation from simplified Chinese to traditional Chinese. In what you cited above, 醜 should be 丑。

Comment: I don't think there is a direct link between 醜 and 丑. 丑 is the same as "clown" - 丑角. While the clown does not look good with facial makeup, it is far from ugly (醜), which is a person's natural facial appearance. Another usage of 丑 is time - 子, 丑, 寅....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

羞 didn't originally mean shame/shy and 丑 didn't originally mean ugly.

丑 is originally a hand with curled fingers, later borrowed to become an earthly branch. Ugly, and all its associated meanings like disgrace, shame, and even clown were originally 醜, which became replaced with 丑 in 'simplified' Chinese. I believe 丑 was borrowed as part of 羞.

羞 is a hand 手 holding a lamb 羊, to offer it as a sacrifice or for food, originally meaning "offering". The hand got changed into 丑, which doubles up as phonetic component.
Offering is now written as 馐.

羞 earlier on had its meaning shifted to become shame or shy, possibly because lambs and sheep are shy and timid creatures, while ugly was still written as 醜.

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%A6%90

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%BE%9E

Answer (score 1):

The character 「丑」 is **not related** to the character 「醜」. Correspondingly, there is **no relation** between 「羞」 and 「醜」. 「丑」 is exclusively used nowadays for the meaning *second [earthly branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthly_Branches#Twelve_branches)*; PRC's usage of 「丑」 to mean *ugly* is a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Phono-semantic_compound_characters), and is not shared among other character-using languages.

---

The character system and the Chinese language don't really work around "Simplified Chinese", which is really just a drastically changed writing standard made up in the 20th century and (for all intents and purposes) only used in the PRC. I would suggest not to think like this,

> Since 醜 is the traditional version of 丑

which is backwards logic, but rather

> PRC changed 「醜」 into 「丑」

because knowing that it is almost always PRC and “Simplified Chinese” which did something bizarre, one can more easily pick out nonsense like this:

> (會意兼形聲。據甲骨文,以手持羊,表示進獻。小篆從羊,從醜,醜亦聲。“醜”是手的訛變。本義:進獻)

The above sentence is an incredibly sloppy **machine conversion** of the following "Simplified Chinese" sentence:

> (会意兼形声。据甲骨文,以手持羊,表示进献。小篆从羊,从丑,丑亦声。“丑”是手的讹变。本义:进献)

The correct interpretation of this sentence is

> #### 羞
>
> 會意兼形聲。據甲骨文，以「手」持「羊」，表示進獻。小篆从「羊」，从「丑」，「丑」亦聲。「丑」是「手」的訛變。本義：進獻.
>
> 「羞」, classified as simultaneously [compound-semantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Compound_ideographs) and [phono-semantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Phono-semantic_compound_characters). Based on [oracle bone script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script), 「羞」 depicts a *hand* 「手」 grasping a *sheep* 「羊」, representing the meaning *to respectfully offer [something]*. In [small seal script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script), it is comprised of semantic 「羊」 and simultaneously semantic and phonetic 「丑」, where 「丑」 is a graphical corruption of 「手」. Original meaning: *to respectfully offer [something]*.

This description is not *quite* right, because it muddles the description of character components; specifically, whoever wrote this mixed up the character [「手」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=129) with the character [「又」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20), which are distinct. Although both 「手」 and 「又」 represent *hands*, characters point to distinct words which involve **different sounds**, and 「手」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*n̥uʔ/**) is not etymologically related to 「又」 (**/*[ɢ]ʷəʔ/**, *right hand*, now written as 「右」).

---

### Glyph origin of 「羞」

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image: ⿸羊又] | [甲](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2006 [合集30768](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=30768&jgwfl=) |
| [春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: ⿸羊又] | 洹子孟姜壺 [集成9729](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=9729&jgwfl=) |
| [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: ⿸羊又] | 語書11 [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts) |
| [西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image: 羞] | 有司53 武威漢簡 |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 羞] |  |

<kbd>[image: ⿸羊又]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: ⿸羊又]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: ⿸羊又]</kbd>
　<kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B8%E5%AE%9A)
[image: ⿸羊又]</kbd>

「羞」 (**/*s-nu/**) was originally 「⿸羊又」, comprised of semantic [「羊」 (*sheep*)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2288) and semantic [「又」 (*right hand*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20) > *actions*), indicating the meaining *to respectfully offer [something]*.

<kbd>[image: 羞]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 羞]</kbd>

「又」 was later slightly shape-changed into [「丑」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=64) (**/*[n̥]ruʔ/**) to additionally give a sound hint.

> *Sheep* were one of the most important livestock animals during the [Shāng period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty), commonly kept in pens for sacrificial purposes and used as tributes and offerings. From [《甲骨文合集》32420](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=32420&jgwfl=):
>
> [image: 《甲骨文合集》32420]
>
> > 丁戼（卯）鼎（貞）：＂／
> > 王（其）爯（琡），／
> > 尞（燎）三「」，／
> > 戼（劉）...... 牢？／
> > ＂
> >
> > [Divination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone#Shang_divination) on the day of [*dīngmǎo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%81%E5%8D%AF), it is asked: "Shall the king offer up a ceremonial jade weapon, conduct a burning ritual with three **penned sheep**, and perform a slaughtering ritual......penned cattle?"

---

### Glyph origin of 「丑」

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 商 甲 | [image: 丑] | [菁](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3.1 [合集10405](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=10405&jgwfl=) |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) 金 | [image: 丑] | 作冊夨令簋 [集成4300](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=4300&jgwfl=) |
| 西周 金 | [image: 丑] | 同簋蓋 [集成4270](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=4270&jgwfl=) |
| 秦 簡 | [image: 丑] | 日書乙種31 睡虎地秦簡 |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) 隸 | [image: 丑] | 僖卅二年 熹平石經 |
| 楷 | [image: 丑] |  |

「丑」 depicts [*a hand* 「又」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20) with long fingernails, indicating the original meaning *clawed hand*. This word is now more commonly written with the variant character [「爪」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=149) (**/*[ts]ˤuʔ/**); the meaning *second [earthly branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthly_Branches#Twelve_branches)* (**/*[n̥]ruʔ/**) is a phonetic loan.

---

### Glyph origin of 「醜」

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 商 甲 | [image: 醜] | [續](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)4.9.2 [合集12878](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=12878&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state)) 玉片文字 | [image: 醜] | 侯馬盟書 戰國文字編 |
| 秦 簡 | [image: 醜] | 語書12 睡虎地秦簡 |
| 東漢 隸 | [image: 醜] | 譙敏碑 |
| 楷 | [image: 醜] |  |

「醜」 (**/*t.qʰuʔ/**, *ugly*) is made up of semantic [「鬼」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1960) (*monster*) and phonetic [「酉」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=718) (**/*N-ruʔ/**).

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 劉釗《古文字構形學》
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 0):

害羞 (shy) is Mandarin

怕醜 (shy) is Cantonese

羞 is not simplified to 丑, the simplified character of 羞 is still 羞

I suspect 醜(ugly) was mistaken as 羞(shame/shy) by a Cantonese editor and simplified to 丑 (ugly/shame/shy) using the lower part of 羞. I meant whoever simplified  醜 to 丑 must have known/thought 羞 and 醜 contain the same meaning of 'shame' therefore, 丑 is a valid simplified character for 醜. and left the character 羞 not simplified